# Is there a way for a set of class methods to know when call is terminated?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object, ecmascript-6

Libraries like `lodash` implement a `.chain()` method in which each subsequent chained method will return a reference to `this` allowing for the chaining to be possible. The downside of which is that at the end of the chain, to resolve the set of functions the `.value()` method needs to be called to return the resulting value.

I am curious is there is away to know if the chain is terminated without the resolver function? Is there a way for each individual method to know if there is a subsequent call and if not return the resulting value?

Here's an example:

```
enum Direction {
    LEFT = 'LEFT',
    UP = 'UP',
    DOWN = 'DOWN',
    RIGHT = 'RIGHT',
}

class Move {
    movement: Direction[];
    constructor () {
        this.movement = []
    }
    left () {
        this.movement.push(Direction.LEFT)
        return this
    }
    right () {
        this.movement.push(Direction.RIGHT)
        return this
    }
    up () {
        this.movement.push(Direction.UP)
        return this
    }
    down () {
        this.movement.push(Direction.DOWN)
        return this
    }
    resolve () {
        return this.movement;
    }
}

const m = new Move()

const code = m
    .up()
    .up()
    .down()
    .down()
    .left()
    .right()
    .left()
    .right()
    .resolve();

console.log(code)
```

I am looking for a way to have the following and still have the same value as the `m` above, by somehow altering each method.

```
const code = m
    .up()
    .up()
    .down()
    .down()
    .left()
    .right()
    .left()
    .right();
```

Comment: Pretty sure no, the only thing that comes semi-close would be to have a `valueOf` method, and coerce the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, there is a pattern that allows this termination:

```
input.pipe(up(), up(), left());
```

By making the functions standalone and "piping" them, you know the chain ended inside `pipe` (note that these would have to be higher-order functions). This pattern is used by rxjs, for example, though there they don't care about termination of the chain at all. The reason it is done there (which is also nice) is that it gives you an easily extensible system of operators that can be tree-shaken.

Similarly you can get back to dot chaining (if you really want it) by just wrapping the chain:

```
input.chain(chain => chain.left().up());
```

The `chain` method can run the function provided to it and knows that at the end of this, the chain is terminated. So assuming your functions return an object with a `value` method, `pipe`/`chain` can just implicitly call this in the end:

```
chain(chainer: (obj: MyObj) => MyObj) { 
  return chainer(this).value(); 
}
```

Of course, essentially this is moving the burden of calling `value` in the end to calling the chain in the beginning.

---

One additional note, I would probably not implement the class to have this mutable state but, if you go with chaining, instead go the route of using an immutable object and each such operator returning a new object. This makes the chain behavior more predictable and sensible as you don't run the risk of applying a chain sequence twice etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way for each individual method to know if there is a subsequent call and if not return the resulting value?

No. You can use a timeout which is essentially *polling* and unreliable.

## Real World

Needing a resolution method is not new e.g. Underscore uses the pair `chain` and `value` : https://underscorejs.org/#chaining

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i think this is pretty conclusive.

Comment: I added a real world example